# Usercontrol binding - RelativeSource

Tags: user-controls, windows-8

In a WPF 4 UserControl I could define the bindings of a sub control in XAML something like this ...

```
...
    <ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding CBItems, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        ...              
    />
...
```

where CBItems is a property defined in the code behind of the UserControl.

However this format isn't available in Windows 8 Metro - RelativeSource does not have a member AncestorType.

How can I do this type of binding in Windows 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though TemplatedControl rather than UserControl is the way to go to create reusable compound components for Windows 8 metro development.

[This blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx) by Tim Heuer has a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to Bind the ItemsSource of your `ComboBox` to a public property of a control you have within the same `UserControl`?

Cant you just do:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CBItems, ElementName=MyControl}"/>
...
<controls:MyUserControl x:name="MyControl" />
```

Comment: The problem is that the name of the control isn't known inside the user control definition.